# how to work two seperate docker-compose files with traefik where swarm enabled

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I have two different docker-compose file having different services(project space) which I want to run on same swarm because I want to use traefik as reverse proxy how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a common image registry and prebuild images before deploying to swarm:

first compose file:

```
services:
    my_service:
        build: ./my_service
        image: my-registry-host/my_service:latest
        ...
```

second compose file:

```
services:

    my_other_service:
        build: ./my_other_service
        image: my-registry-host/my_other_service:latest
        ...
    my_service:
        image: my-registry-host/my_service:latest
        ...

    traefik:
        image: traefik:v2.0
        ...
```

when you build the services in the first file they are uploaded to your common registry **my-registry-host**. An when you deploy the second file you will see that the image will be got from the common registry and stack runs as expected.